# Can't get SHA-1 fingerprint from signature.jks

Tags: android, sha1, jks

i have a huge problem: i don't know how to get the SHA-1 fingerprint from the file that i use to sign my app. Let's assume that my jks file (generated from Android Studio) is named "signature.jks". How can i get the SHA-1 fingerprint?

I tried with this syntax:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\apkname.keystore -alias apkname
```

Where "apkname" is the name of the apk and "E" is the disk where my jks file is stored.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: any error message displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, sorry everybody, problem solved, i have typed the wrong path to my keystore file(the file with .jks extension), and after "-alias" i put the name of the apk instead the name of the alias, so the correct syntax was:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\signature.jks -alias aliasName
```

Answer (score 0):

alias name is not mandatory.
For me following worked:

keytool -keystore "C:\signature.jks" -list -v